# every number $n\in \mathbb{Z} $ can be represented as sum of different powers of $2$

Tags: generating-functions, number-systems

Using generating function prove that every number $n\in \mathbb{Z} $ can be represented as sum of different power of $2$,
I mean, that for every $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ $$n=2^{k_1} +2^{k_2} +2^{k_3} +...  $$ where $k_i \neq k_j  $
Please give me some advices.

Comment: its same as saying that every integer has a binary representation, google to see why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint* Prove that $\displaystyle  \prod_{\nu\geqslant 0}(1+x^{2^{\nu}})=\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots.$ Note that this proves existence and uniqueness.

Comment: How do you get?\\
$ \prod_{\nu\geqslant 0}(1+x^{2^{\nu}})$

Comment: It took me like two minutes to understand this. I think it's a little too kryptic. Although I have to give it to you. It is pretty pleasent when you get it.+1

Comment: @user180834 I don't understand your question. It would be a shame if I spoil it for you.

Comment: ok, I try do it ;)